# How to communicate between programs on same machine?

Tags: json, web-services, ipc

My setup is as follows: one **master program** (written in Python) acts as main application that retrieves data, which is saved to a SQLite DB (and then further processed later on). This data is gathered within other programs, running on the **same machine**, called **slaves**.

Note that there is always only one slave running at a time, so the master does not need to retrieve data from multiple slaves simultaneously. However, when one slave shuts down, another slave can start to send data to the master.

An important feature of this setup is that the **slaves** can be written in **any programming language**, I do not have much control over them. I can however "plug in" to these slave programs in order extend their functionality and to send data from that application to the master.

Data sent to the master must be in a "formal" format, e.g. a list of key/value pairs, or alike. That requirement is kind of flexible, it also depends on which slave is currently running.

Now to my question: How can I achieve that communication between instances of running programs on the same machine? I thought about **web services**, but they seem a bit of an overkill, as all is running on the same host. Another alternative could be communication of **Json-based data via sockets**, but I have not yet made much experience with such an approach, so that I cannot tell whether it would suit my needs in this case.

These two approaches are just my first ideas though, I am open to any good solution.

I would think there is kind of a "best practice" approach how to implement such a setup, as I am surely not the first one with such requirements.

Any ideas, or even better: practical experience, on that?
Thanks.

Comment: What stops you from using persistant storage?

Comment: You mean via a DB or a file?
Wouldn't that be slower than eg. via sockets?
But as said I am open minded here -- what are the advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cross-platform ways to communicate between processes, but I see no reasons not to use a tcp socket for this.

Example: `mongod` is the daemon process of MongoDB, other processes communicate with it just through an ordinary tcp socket (see [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/)).

Comment: Yeah maybe sockets are indeed a good solution. But what format should data then be represented in? Json, or is there a better, "standard" way to transfer data via sockets?

Comment: @Matthias I see json is handy enough. Traditional XML may be a choice as well. Both are widely used.